# Can't login to my wordpress, phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm looking into my local wp-config and I see this:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
define('DB_USER', 'wordpress');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

But no matter which combination I use I can't login to phpmyadmin, how can I troubleshoot this so I can see my database tables?

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to login to your phpmyadmin using localhost. You'll need to ask your hosts what the actual IP or Address is.

Comment: well this is on my local drive so are you saying I just punch in my ip address or whatever my local address name is?